# SQL Query - Order by with limit does not work correctly

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for this... and I have no idea why it doesn't work :X Any suggestions?

```
$this->db->from("twitch");
$this->db->where(array('banned' => 0));
$this->db->order_by("viewers", "DESC");
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

The result is not ordered by viewers DESC (or on the main page - 0 viewers and on the last page - 2000 viewers)

Model Function - http://pastebin.com/yqwvZEQ1
View - http://pastebin.com/gL95uDR6

Comment: what is the output and sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$this->db->from('twitch')->where('banned'=>0)->order_by("viewers", "DESC")->limit($limit, $start);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Try with chaining method of codeigniter. For more information you can see documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: what difference does it make with chaining method?

Comment: $data=$this->db->where('banned'=>0)->order_by("viewers", "DESC")->limit($limit, $start)->get('twitch')->result();

Comment: No success. Still doesn't order them by viewers DESC.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->
    where(array('banned' => 0))->
    order_by('viewers', 'DESC')->
    limit($limit, $start)->
    get('twitch');
```

Do you use MySQL? Because this LIMIT syntax works only in MySQL. Also make sure you've defined $limit and $start values.

Comment: Same here - not being ordered by viewers DESC

Comment: Try to change `limit($limit, $start)->` to `limit(20)->` and check if order is proper now. Also could you please show us your PHP code which displays the list of viewers?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$this->db->order_by("viewers", "DESC");
$this->db->where("banned", "0"));
$query = $this->db->get("twitch");
```

Just changed the order of the functions used. `limit` should be first - otherwise it won't limit the *un*ordered *un*filtered data.

Comment: what difference does it make?

Comment: Once I stucked like this only and this worked for me.

Comment: this is no logical reason

Comment: Same goes for this... It can't order them by viewers DESC :X